# How can I fix python multiprocessing error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am starting to learn about python multiprocessing. I am starting with this simple code. I am using Anaconda and the Spyder IDE to implement this code in. I am using Windows 10 Pro Operating System.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print('Sleeping for 1 second ...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done Sleeping ...')


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} in seconds')
```

When I run the above code I get the following error message:

```
Finished in 0.15 in seconds

Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'do_something' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'do_something' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'do_something' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'do_something' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I can see that is printed the last print statement but then it gives me the above error. Why do I get this error? What do I need to do to the code to fix this error?

Comment: This is an operating system dependent issue - please include your operating system.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro operating system.

Comment: It is generally advised but especially important on Windows to guard your process spawning with `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score -2):

I was in your situation just a few months ago and I ended up having more success with concurrent.future than multiprocessing.

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

def some_cpu_bound_task(num):
    print(f"in cpu task {num}")
    range_to_sum = list(range(int(10000000)))  # create a big list to sum
    result = sum(range_to_sum)  # sum the list (CPU-intensive)
    return num ** 3  # return result of power operation

def some_io_bound_task(num):
    print(f"in io task {num}")
    time.sleep(10)  # simulated I/O delay
    return num * num

def start_calculations():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(16) as executor:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(16):
            tasks.append(executor.submit(some_cpu_bound_task, i))
            tasks.append(executor.submit(some_io_bound_task, i))
    return tasks

def wait_all_calculations(tasks):
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
        result = future.result()
        print(f"Result: {result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    all_tasks = start_calculations()
    wait_all_calculations(all_tasks)
```

I think your code might not work because you need to be in **main**, like the examples in the docs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. The purpose of answers here is to answer the question, not to suggest alternate ways of solving an assumed underlying problem. That is because questions here, in turn, are not about getting personalized help or making the code work, but about contributing to a searchable reference library.